# How to copy or clone model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model Book with attributes id, name, price. I have an instance of Book:

```
b1 = Book.new
b1.name = "Blah"
b1.price = 12.5
b1.save
```

I would like to copy b1, create another instance of the Product model. I'm tryid p1=b1.clone then p1.save but it didn't work. Any idea?

And my environment is:

- Netbeans 6.9 RC2
- JRuby 1.5.0

**EDITED:**
My TemporaryProduct model:

```
class Admin::TemporaryProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.update_from_web_service(web_service_url)
    response = HTTParty.get(web_service_url)
    response["webServiceResult"]["product"].each do|element|
      unless exists? :orignal_product_id => element['id']
        create!(
          :name => element['name'],
          :price => element['price'],
          :amount => element['amount'],
          :description => element['description'],
          :orignal_product_id => element['id'],
          :image => element['image'],
          :shop_account_number => element['shopAccountNumber'],
          :unit => element['unit']
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Product is create action:

```
  def create
    @temporary_products = Admin::TemporaryProduct.find_all_by_orignal_product_id(params[:product])
    @product = Admin::Product.new(@temporary_products.attributes)
    # @product = @temporary_products.clone
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(admin_products_url, :notice => 'Admin::Product was successfully created.') }
    end
  end
```

I want to clone all b1's attributes to p1 model.

Comment: In your posted `create` action, `@temporary_products` will be an array of objects of type `Admin::TemporaryProduct`. `attributes` is a method of a single instance. I'm not quite clear whether you want to clone all the results, or just one, or whether you expect `find_all_by_original_product_id` to return only 1 result.

Comment: I don't think so. It's return an array.

Comment: Yes, I know it returns an array. Therefore `@temporary_products.attributes` won't work, because `.attributes` is a method of a *single instance*. Are you trying to clone all the temporary products returned, or just one?

Comment: Okay i understood. I'm just trying to clone all the temporary products. But it's work. I get an errors.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

I think you want:

```
b2 = Book.create(b1.attributes)
```

**Edit:**
Given your `create` action above, I think what you want to do is change the line which starts `@product` to

```
@temporary_products.each {|tp| Admin::Product.create(tp.attributes)}
```

That will create a new `Product` object for each `TemporaryProduct` object, using the same attributes as the `TemporaryProduct`. If that's not what you want, let me know.

Comment: b1.attributes function not found!

Comment: b1 = Admin::TemporaryProduct, p1 = Admin::Product

Comment: b1 = Admin::TemporaryProduct.new, p1 = Admin::Product.new

Answer (score 1):

You can make duplicate record using `dup` in rails For Example,

```
b1 = Book.create(name: "example", price: 120)
b1.save
duplicate_record = b1.dup
duplicate_record.save!
```

or you can create first new record and then make a duplicate

Hope this is useful for you.

Comment: I think this is the most idiomatic answer.

Answer (score 0):

If by didn't work you mean that there is no new record in the database then you probably want to set the id of p1 to null before you save. If the clone has the same id as the original then it would appear to represent the same object.